# Touchscreen woes: Attempt to scroll using touchscreen is recognized as a click and drag/select

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, gui, touchscreen

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a HP Envy 4t-1105dx with touchscreen.  Everything except Wifi (Atheros AR9565 doesn't work out of the box) and touchscreen (mostly working) works.

I believe that the Envy i have has an Atmel Maxtouch Digitizer.

When I'm on Firefox and certain other programs, attempting to scroll using the touchscreen si recognized as a click and drag/select motion as if I were holding down the mouse button to drag and highlight something.

Using the scroll bar on the side works.

Drag scrolling in Documents Viewer works.

---

Another problem is that while clicking generally works on the touchscreen, when I try to click folders or files using the touchscreen in Nautilus, the file/folder is only highlight.

---

Besides this problem using the touchscreen is fine save for the lack of gestures in gnome shell.  Utouch is not in 12.10 anymore sadly.  Why  I have no idea.

Answer (score 4):

To get touch scrolling in Firefox working, install this addon extension [Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grab-and-drag/?src=ss)

It's an addon called Grab and Drag. It allows you to scroll using the touchscreen in the same fashion as a tablet or smartphone.

Double tapping on the screen should also open files and folders in nautilus.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the extension.  Everything except momentum works.  I'm still tinkering with the settings to get it working. Nautilus won't open the folders no matter how much I click them.  Even setting the clicking as single click to open the holders doesn't work.  clicking everything else works though.  Clicking bookmarks works just fine.

Comment: I've got momentum working, but not very well. Maybe it's because I don't have a touchscreen computer. I've set "Time Sensitivity" to its lowest setting and "Deceleration Sensitivity" about three-fourths of the way. Friction is still at the default setting.

Answer (score 2):

The failure to trigger actions by double tapping the touchscreen in nautilus is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7/+bug/1071922 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1002788

Switching to "Single click to open items" (nautilus->edit->preferences->behavior->) does not help. You can, however, switch to list view (nautilus->view->list). In list view the touchscreen works as expected. That doesn't help directly with the desktop items, but you can go to home/user/Desktop in nautilus in list view and trigger actions from there.

Comment: Thanks.  It works that way but unfortunately, I still can't right click in any way with the touchscreen.

Answer (score 0):

One setting you could change is the 'Single click to open files'. When this is active, you will have to tap and hold the itens to select.

I have been strugling with scrolling with touchscreen for some time now as well, without  much success. While firefox and chrome have some extensions to make that work, there are other applications that still dont work very well (for instance the unity launcher)

Comment: I'm running GNOME Shell and Nautilus 3.6.  I can't seem to find that option.